# How do I download a video from Pexels website?

Tags: python, video, python-requests, download

I have a code that is trying to download a video from the Pexels website. Pexels does not require you to be logged in to download (verified in a private browser). Here is my code, but the file is 3 KB.

```
import requests
video = 'https://www.pexels.com/video/a-rocky-river-in-the-forest-5896379/'
d = requests.get(video)
with open('test.mp4', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(d)
```

Just trying to understand why my code is wrong.

Comment: If the file is 3kb, it means you got *something*, but not what you expected, so your first question should be "what exactly did I get?"  Try looking at the file, or opening that URL in a web browser.

Comment: @Samwise actually now that I rerun the code again i get the "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Response'"

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation for [`requests.Response`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.content) to see how you get the data you want out of a Response object.

Comment: @mnnewbilr About what's wrong with your code: **(1)** Your link is to a web page (HTML text document). It's not a video file that you can save. **(2)** You need to treat the download as a received text **String** and then search that HTML text for the MP4 link within the page source. **(3)** The MP4 link is from the starting **position** of text `"contentUrl":"` up to the first found `"` after that starting position. You will want to extract a **subString** that keep the `https://` part onwards until the `"` quotation mark's position but minus 1 character.

Comment: @mnnewbilr. Example of text of URL to extract from String of web page code: `"contentUrl":"https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761"` ... Remove the starting 14 characters and also remove the last 1 character, then finally [test the link](https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761) in a browser. If it plays that's the path for MP4 bytes to save in your code

Comment: @VC.One link = 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761' d = requests.get(link)
    
    with open('test.mp4','wb') as f:
        f.write(d.content) - but still doesnt work

Comment: You have the **correct link** now so really you should be getting the MP4 file bytes sent back to you. I don't use Python so you'll have to investigate further (about file downloading). I was able to save it with PHP (which isn't doing anything special but a simple GET request & write contents to file. Python can do same things).

Comment: @mnnewbilr  PS: Try this alternate link in your GET request: `https://www.pexels.com/video/5896379/download/`. It's a direct link to get MP4 bytes (without involving any HTML text extraction, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Just like mentioned by [VC.One](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057709/vc-one), the possible solution is directed to download through this link `https://www.pexels.com/video/5896379/download/`

This sufficient code should be work (with streaming of the response content and then save the video file using for-loop to write the response content in chunk)

```py
url = "https://www.pexels.com/video/5896379/download/"
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open("video.mp4", "wb") as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        f.write(chunk)
```

If still doesnt work because of error messages like `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='player.vimeo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded`
(which is because the first time i also can't download it), you can disable the verification of SSL with

```py
# same code
response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

Tested using both links, it working